# Cython: C function definition not allowed here

Tags: python, cython

I tried to build pyqt app with cython static typing,
and when I set type of parameter I'll give me error !

```
def Ui_MainWindow(object):
    cpdef object setupUi(object self, object MainWindow):
```

```
def Ui_MainWindow(object):
    cpdef object setupUi(object self, object MainWindow):
                                                       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:8:56: C function definition not allowed here
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Was `def Ui_MainWindow(object)` supposed to say `class` where it says `def`?